# Understanding Quadrants of Trigo problems

Tags: trigonometry

> This is the problem I was solving,$\tan (\sin^{-1} x)$

I have the correct answer, I solve it by evaluating $(\sin^{-1} x)$ and drawing out the right angle triangle, I let $A =(\sin^{-1} x)$ = I got $ \tan A = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Though I got the answer, I looked at the solution and this is what it says:

Let $A=(\sin^{-1} x)$. Then $\sin A=x$ where $A \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and since $\tan (\sin^{-1} x)$ is not defined if $x= +-1$

So, we have $-1 < x < 1$ and note that $0 \le A < \pi /2$ <--> $0 \le x < 1 $ and $ -\pi/2 < A < 0$ <--> $-1<x<0$

This seems to be a very complicated explanation for the start of the question which I cant wrap my head around it, and I'm trying to understand.

I was already lost at $A \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$,

Comment: To make Sense of the Answer, we have to know the Question. Might be good to Post the Exact Question & then the Answer can be Explained. Is this Book written in English or was it translated ? Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics) : Does this help ?

Comment: (A) Problem Is not $\tan(\sin^{−1}(x))$ , It must be some thing like : Evaluate (or give the Expression for) $\tan(\sin^{−1}(x))$ in terms of only $x$ (B) You Specially high-lighted the word "Submersion" but it seems to been entirely removed ?

Comment: Assuming that the Problem is [ Evaluate (or give the Expression for) $\tan(\sin^{−1}(x))$ in terms of only $x$ ] , By Drawing the right angled triangle in the first Quadrant, you have got the Answer only in the first Quadrant. You have to Draw a right angled triangle in the other Quadrant & get the other Part too. In this case, luckily both are same, though there are cases where it changes, atleast with a negative sign or some other constant. The Book is more rigorous to get the Answer without Discontinuity Points. Treating each Quadrant is a common technique to avoid Discontinuity Points.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to realize the proposed identity.

To begin with, let us set that $\arcsin:(-1,1)\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Then we conclude that:
\begin{align*}
\tan(\arcsin(x)) = \frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\cos(\arcsin(x))} = \frac{\sin(\arcsin(x))}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^{2}(\arcsin(x))}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!